# How to implement Email Anonymization Similar to Craigslist

Tags: email, craigslist

I am developing a site for which I would like to protect buyers by anonymizing their email addresses.Similar to craigslist's system, when a seller needs to contact a buyer they should be able to send an email to an anonymized address such as 142jijisds@mysite.com which will then be routed to the user's email address.

But I don't know how to implement this feature.